# Scrapy module not found for a web crawling script

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler

I have scrapy version 1.4 and python 3. I am trying to use scrapy with python, however, whenever I run `python3 script.py`, I get a return error

```
File "script.py", line 2, in <module>
    from scrapy import Spider
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scrapy'
```

However, the imports are below

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from scrapy import Spider
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from stack.items import StackItem

class StackSpider(Spider):
```

When I run `pip show scrapy`

```
Name: Scrapy
Version: 1.4.0
Summary: A high-level Web Crawling and Web Scraping framework
...
```

Comment: pip is python2, but you are using python3!

Comment: I feel rather stupid. How should I install pip using python 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should install `scrapy` for python3 via `pip3 install scrapy` if you want to code in python3.

Comment: Quick question, then whenever I run scrapy, which version will it run? `scrapy crawl script` unless there is `scrapy3 crawl script` or something?

Comment: Isn't that `python script.py` or `python3 script.py`?

Comment: well, I am amateur to python, but the script is just a spider. I actually run it by using `scrapy crawl script`

Comment: I actually don't use `scrapy` so I don't know. You can refer to [scrapy doc](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html) for more info. `python xxx.py` is to run a python script.